# JSPのsubmit()をJAVAで行うにはどうしたらよいのか？

Tags: java

下記のコードを、Javaで代用するにはどのようにしたら良いのでしょうか？

アドバイスをいただければ幸いです。

```
<a href="javascript:doSubmit()">ページの移動</a>

function doSubmit() {
    document.form.mode.value="abc";
    document.form.action="./test.do";
    document.form.submit();
}
```

下記の様なコードで行おうとしましたが、sendDataの内容がうまく送れないようで、ページの遷移がうまくいきません。

```
    String sendData = "mode=\"REF\"" +
                      "&action=\"./test.do\"";

    url = new URL("https://www.test.com/main.do");
    con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    os = con.getOutputStream();

    osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "utf-8");
    osw.write(sendData);
    osw.close();

    isr = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), "utf-8");
    br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           response += line;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpURLConnection#connect() を実行すると実際に接続が行われますので osw.close() のあとに con.connect() を追加してみてください。